# ggplot making a chart beautiful

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to improve my chart on two different points.

I don't like the numbers on the bottom line so they have to be removed.
I want the data label behind the chart and not half in it.

**Code for the calculation**

```
select f.ClubName, round(w.Waarde/w.Selectie,0) as Gem_waarde
from fact f
join waarde w
on w.WDID = f.WDID
order by Gem_waarde desc
```

**Chart code**

```
ggplot(df_5, aes(x = fct_reorder(ClubName, Gem_waarde), y = Gem_waarde,fill = as_factor(ClubName))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge2") +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  coord_flip() +
  #ylim(20000,5000000)+
  labs(x = "Club", y = "waarde per speler") +
    geom_text(aes(label = Gem_waarde, Gem_waarde = Gem_waarde + 0.05),
    position = position_dodge(0.9),vjust = 0)
```

[image]

```
Example Data
Club Selectie waarde
1   29  375900000
2   26  211500000
3   28  94780000
4   25  74050000
5   25  44300000
6   27  31050000
7   26  20980000
8   27  19480000
9   25  18980000
10  28  17580000
11  29  17330000
12  26  16330000
13  30  14180000
14  21  14000000
15  28  12330000
16  27  12280000
17  31  11930000
18  28  960000
```

Comment: Consider adding example data to your code to make it [a great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added some data now

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right, you want that labels to be plotted into each bar chart not outside. For that, you can use `hjust` argument in `geom_label`.

To remove numbers on the bottom line, you can use `axis.text.x = element_blank()`. 
I don't think you really need to use `position_dodge` in your plot.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(Variable, Value), y = Value, fill = Variable))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Value), hjust = 2)+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

**EDIT: With OP data**

With the example data you provided, the issue came from the large spread of values, so labeling each barplot with their values will be quite complicated as obviously, `960000` is not going to fit into its corresponding barplot.

My personal advices will be to `round` this data to the million and also to change the `y` scale in order that no values will be put outside the graph. Then set `hjust` to 1 in order to have the number right aligned on the top of its corresponding barplot.

In code, it looks like that:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(as.factor(Club), waarde), y = waarde, fill = as.factor(waarde)))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(waarde/1000000," M")), hjust = 1)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-15,380)*1000000)+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Does it look satisfying for your you ?

**Data - Initial example**

```r
df = data.frame(Variable = LETTERS[1:10],
                Value = sample(1:1000,10))
```

Comment: Yes something like that

Comment: I edited my answer based on data you provided. Let me know if it looks satisying to you.